# Spark Structured streaming: get second row of 1 minute window aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming where I need to take value from the second row of the window.

let say this is the data in my 1-minute window

```
|| second | col1 | col 2 ||
===========================
     1        a      b
     2        c      d
     .        .      .
     60       x      y
```

So basically I want to refer to the second row in my windows aggregation i.e.

```
|| second | col1 | col 2 ||
===========================
     2        c      d
```

I am able to refer to the first and last easily in aggregate operation as there is first() and last() function are available

```
 val aggregates = dataEvents
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "5 seconds")
  .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "1 minute", "1 minute", "0 seconds"))
  .agg(
    first("col1").alias("first"), // This i have to make from second row.
    last("col1").alias("last")
    )
```